# Can SignalR Client 1.x connect to SignalR Server 2.x?

Tags: javascript, signalr, owin

I have a project using SignalR v1.x with IIS hosted server. 
Now i want to upgrade server side to 2.x with self hosted by windows service.
But i want to keep client side in SignalR version 1.x.
Can i?

Comment: Why not make a simple test project to find out? Then post the findings back here as I'd be interested to know.

Comment: is there any update testing?